# How to merge video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 2 videos, 1920x1080.
I want merge them vertically, such way, that total videos will be 1920x1080, i.e they both are compressed twice vertically.

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -i test.avi  -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1920:540[up]; \
 [1:v]scale=1920:540[bottom]; \
 [up][bottom]vstack" \
output2.mp4
```

I've tried code above, but this keeps ratio.. and I have video like 600x1080 in the middle.

Comment: Well, these commands doesn't change aspect ratio.
To change it use setdar. ie setdar=16:4 for make 16:4.

Answer (score 1):

`scale` alters output SAR to maintain the input's DAR.  Set SAR to `1` after scaling.

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -i test.avi  -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1920:540,setsar=1[up]; \
 [1:v]scale=1920:540,setsar=1[bottom]; \
 [up][bottom]vstack" \
output2.mp4
```

Comment: Yes, I did it.
Is it possible to make second video twice wider? I've traid pad&overlay, setsar.. no idea.
Tnank you

Comment: I did: `ffmpeg -i test.avi -vf "[in] scale=iw:ih/2, pad=2*iw:2*ih [left]; 
    movie=test.avi, scale=2*iw:ih/2[right]; 
    [left][right] overlay=0:main_h/2 [out]" Output.mp4`